# Javascript - Flash Sound Recording

Tags: jquery, html, red5, audio-recording

I would like to capture sound from a browser and send it to a server.
I decided to use `red5` for the reasons listed on this [interesting page](http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/) that claims to do exactly what I need.

It requires the following:

- A running red5 server
- A flash object that can capture the microphone input
- A JavaScript controller

I tried to implement this [example](http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/new/) localy (I pretty much simply copied all the files). At page load from my server console I can see that the supplied flash object `audioRecorder1.swf` creates a connection.

> [INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect
>   [INFO] [NioProcessor-1] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Connecting to: [WebScope@4799a84f Depth = 1, Path = '/default', Name = 'oflaDemo']

But when I hit any button (record/play/stop) of the controller, I'm having this javascript error from which I can't figure out the origin

> thisMovie("denRecorder").jsRecord is not a function

`denRecorder` is the id of the flash object in the page (created with the `swfobject.js` library)

```
<object width="1" height="1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="denRecorder" name="denRecorder" data="/static/flash/audioRecorder.swf">
  <param name="menu" value="false">
  <param name="flashvars" value="myServer=rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo&amp;mySound=snd_88188160112&amp;myDuration=0">
</object>
```

I have created a [package](http://v8.westmill.net/tmp/testRecorder.tar.gz) that can be tested localy.

Do you have any idea of what is my problem ?

**edit**

OS: Ubuntu, Browser: Chromium & Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a [project](https://github.com/jfrec/jfrec) (OSS) with someone which will help us for this question